# Upload many layers from PostGIS database to GeoServer using curl

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, curl

I have more than 200 layers in my PostGIS database and I want to publish those layers in GeoServer using curl. I've imported one layer using the command below but can't figure out how to upload all layers in one step.

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<featureType><name>testlayer</name></featureType>" http://localhost:8088/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/datastores/mystore/featuretypes
```

Comment: Use a loop and pass the layer names?

Comment: I am not familiar with curl, could you describe me how?

Comment: I meant, use some script to execute the command in a loop. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32791680/5355375

Comment: Are you willing to use any other tool or language, for instance Python? Or are you looking for a pure command line-based approach?

Comment: I've tried to use gsonfig tool https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig#installing but couldn't install it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any programming language eg: Java, Phython etc. Where you can run your command in for loop and change parameter 'name' with your layer name in each iteration.

Comment: I wanted to do it in a cmd but I managed to do it like u said, Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Example of a simple bash script to create Geoserver layers for all tables of a given Postgresql schema.

The workspace and the store should already exist in Geoserver. In this example I use the *workspace name = database name*; the *store name = schema name*; *postgresql server = geoserver server*. That is why my URL is: `http://$pghost/geoserver/rest/workspaces/$pgdb/datastores/$pgschema/featuretypes`

```
#!/bin/bash

pghost='server.com'
pgport=5432
pguser='geobox'
pgpass='******'
pgschema='sigpdm_2015'
pgdb='pdm2017'

table_names=`PGPASSWORD=$pgpass psql -U $pguser -h $pghost -p $pgport -d $pgdb -t -c "SELECT * FROM (select table_name as t from information_schema.tables where table_schema = '$pgschema') as tnames"`

while read -a table_name ; do
    curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<featureType><name>$table_name</name><nativeCRS>EPSG:3763</nativeCRS><srs>EPSG:3763</srs><nativeBoundingBox><minx>-33313.0</minx><maxx>-13047.0</maxx><miny>198924.0</miny><maxy>216948.0</maxy><crs>EPSG:3763</crs></nativeBoundingBox></featureType>" http://$pghost/geoserver/rest/workspaces/$pgdb/datastores/$pgschema/featuretypes
done <<< "$table_names"
```

The `<featureType>` could be more simpler, but I usually run into problems when layers get new features outside the initial bounding box. So I prefer to create the layers with the larger possible bounding box. I also added the local CRS, instead of a global one.